# Harnack inequality for fractional laplacian

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let u be a positive solution of $s\in (0, 1) $
\begin{equation}
 \left\{\begin{aligned}
 (-\Delta )^{s} u &= 0  \text{ in } (-2T, 2T)\\
u &=g\quad\text{in}\quad \mathbb R\setminus(-2T, 2T).
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}
 If $u \in C^2(-T, T)\cap C^1 [-T, T]$ and $g$ is a bounded positive function on $\mathbb R$, is there a Harnack inequality in one dimension for the above kind of equation.

Answer (score 2):

Harnack's inequality for the fractional Laplace operator was proved already by [M. Riesz](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjbjPPHgtPcAhUmDZoKHXdqA4wQFjAAegQICRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Facta.bibl.u-szeged.hu%2F13487%2F1%2Fmath_009_001-042.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0j6-XhHUfpNpq5tfH8Zxdw) in 1938. For an exact statement and further information, see Lemma 2.1 in [R.F. Bass and M. Cranston](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176993502).

By the way, in your case $$\begin{aligned} u(x) & = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1 + s) \lvert\Gamma(-s)\rvert} \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus (-2T,2T)} \biggl( \frac{4 T^2 - x^2}{y^2 - 4 T^2}\biggr)^{\!s} \frac{1}{|x - y|} \, g(y) dy \\ & \qquad + (4 T^2 - 1)^s \biggl(\frac{c_1}{2 T - x} + \frac{c_2}{2 T + x}\biggr) \end{aligned}$$ for $x \in (-2T, 2T)$ for some constants $c_1, c_2 \geqslant 0$ by the result of [K. Bogdan](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.hmj/1206125005) or [Z.-Q. Chen and R. Song](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123698933043) (see also [Hmissi, *Fonctions harmoniques pour les potentiels de Riesz sur la boule unite*, Exposition. Math. 12(3) (1994): 281–288]), without assuming any smoothness of $u$.

Comment: I have changed the question a bit. Through google, I checked there seems to be many types of Harnack inequality. But I am not sure if it is applicable in this case.

Comment: I updated the answer and added a reference to Bass–Cranston that might be helpful for you. I am not sure what do you mean by "many types of Harnack inequality", though (parabolic? boundary? for other operators?).

Comment: I am looking for the interior Harnack kind of inequality.

Comment: @sadiaz: Does the Bass–Cranston reference work for you then?